# Why create-react-app alias is not able to find index.js from folder?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I am stuck up with a weird issue while creating alias for my app. I am trying to create the alias adding `jsconfig.json` what looks like

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es2015",
            "es2016",
            "es6",
            "es2017"
        ],
        "target": "es2017",
        "module": "es6",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "actions/*": ["src/actions/*"],
            "public/*": ["public/*"],
            "components/*": ["src/components/*"],
            "containers/*": ["src/containers/*"],
            "constants/*": ["src/constants/*"],
            "config/*": ["config/*"],
            "helpers/*": ["src/helpers/*"],
            "stores/*": ["src/stores/*"],
            "styles/*": ["src/styles/*"]
        }
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/node_modules/*"]
}
```

in this case its not able to find any of the component alias.

I changed the json file to

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es2015",
            "es2016",
            "es6",
            "es2017"
        ],
        "target": "es2017",
        "module": "es6",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "baseUrl": "./src/",
        "paths": {
            "actions/*": ["actions/*"],
            "public/*": ["public/*"],
            "components/*": ["components/*"],
            "containers/*": ["containers/*"],
            "constants/*": ["constants/*"],
            "config/*": ["config/*"],
            "helpers/*": ["helpers/*"],
            "stores/*": ["stores/*"],
            "styles/*": ["styles/*"]
        }
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/node_modules/*"]
}
```

It able to get the component alias however throwing error  `Cannot find file: 'index.js' does not match the corresponding name on disk: './src/components/Checkbox/CheckBox'.` while I am trying to import it as
`import Checkbox from 'components/Checkbox';`.
And my folder structure looks like

```
mainDir/
      config/
      public/
      src/
        component/
          Checkbox/
            index.js
      jsconfig.json
      package.json
```

How do I fix this issue? Is there any other way I can create alias with `create-react-app`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `create-react-app` project, source files outside of `src` folder are not transpiled. [[1]](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/v3.2.0/packages/react-scripts/config/modules.js#L49)

Directly importing from es6 modules that use **JSX syntax** outside of `src` folder fail for this reason.

Common practice is to create symlinks in `src` folder for modules outside it and set up aliases to resolve from the `src` folder. *e.g.*

```
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "paths": {
            "actions": ["actions/*"],
            "public": ["public/*"],
            "components": ["components/*"],
            "containers": ["containers/*"],
            "constants": ["constants/*"],
            "config": ["config/*"],
            "helpers": ["helpers/*"],
            "stores": ["stores/*"],
            "styles": ["styles/*"]
        }
```

Symlink external modules

```sh
ln -s ../config/ ./src/
ln -s ../public/ ./src/
```

Comment: Gussed so. Thanks for clarify that.
Tho I still have the issue for `Cannot find file: 'index.js' does not match the corresponding name on disk: './src/components/Checkbox/CheckBox'.`
Any suggestion how to fix that?

Comment: The folder name in the alias `["components/"]` but that in the project tree you shared is `component`. You should check that and be sure what folder is present on disk to inform the path that is alias.

Comment: So I figured out the issue, `Checkbox/CheckBox` this where its wrong, naming style.  In a place, I had it `Checkbox` and other place `CheckBox`. Fixed it now. Thank you so much.
If I may, I have one more question, it seems fair jsconfig wouldn't let me use alias for scss files. Is there a way I could use alias for scss files as well with this kinda config on `create-react-app`?

Comment: I don't know. Usually CSS-in-JS is the way to go with SPA built in React. You can check if this documentation helps: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

The alias solution for craco or rewired *create-react-app* is **[react-app-alias](https://github.com/oklas/react-app-alias)** for systems as: [craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/blob/master/packages/craco), [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired), [customize-cra](https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra)

According docs of mentioned systems replace `react-scripts` with `craco` in *package.json* and configure next:

```
// craco.config.js
const {CracoAliasPlugin} = require('react-app-alias')

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      plugin: CracoAliasPlugin,
      options: {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Configure aliases in json like this:

```js
// tsconfig.paths.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "example/*": ["example/src/*"],
      "@library/*": ["library/src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

And add this file in `extends` section of main typescript config file:

```js
// tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.paths.json",
  // ...
}
```